# How to change the structure of json while doing df.write in Pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**In Pyspark when I write to json like

```
transformed_noti_overdue_trainee_df.coalesce(1).write.json(f"{storage_url}/path", mode="overwrite")**
```

but its output is :

```
{
    "EmailAddresses": "CDF@CDF.com;CDF@CDa.com",
    "TrainerName": "Person-58",
    "CourseTitle": "Connector Mate/Demate",
    "OverdueCount": 1,
    "DueLessThan31DaysCount": 14
  }
{
    "EmailAddresses": "CD@gg.com;cd@ee.com",
    "TrainerName": "Person-58",
    "CourseTitle": "Connector Mate/Demate",
    "OverdueCount": 1,
    "DueLessThan31DaysCount": 14
  }
```

which is wrong schema of json (I donot get Commas for each row),the logic app which is consuming this , is failing as schema fails,
**I need a schema like:**

```
[
  {
    "EmailAddresses": "abc@.com;cdv@.com",
    "TrainerName": "Person-58",
    "CourseTitle": "CDF",
    "OverdueCount": 1,
    "DueLessThan31DaysCount": 14
  },
  {
    "EmailAddresses": "abc@.com;cdv@.com",
    "TrainerName": "Person-123",
    "CourseTitle": "ABC001",
    "OverdueCount": 0,
    "DueLessThan31DaysCount": 1
  },
  {
    "EmailAddresses": "abc@.com;cdv@.com",
    "TrainerName": "Person-58",
    "CourseTitle": "ABCAddendum",
    "OverdueCount": 0,
    "DueLessThan31DaysCount": 1
  },
  {
    "EmailAddresses": "abc@.com;cdv@.com",
    "TrainerName": "Person-123",
    "CourseTitle": "ABC610",
    "OverdueCount": 0,
    "DueLessThan31DaysCount": 1
  }
]
```